# how to loop through a dictionary within a list using pandas/python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, google-bigquery

I am trying to loop through a json request. i parsed the loop using tags = df1.apply(lambda row: row["tags"],axis= 1)
and the sample of result set is in the below image.
[image]

Now i want to loop through the list and nested dictionary and obtain the value of group and values(keys in dictionary) as saperate fields.

Further, i wish to push them to bigquery. so i need them as individual strings rather than list/dictionary.
Can you please suggest through any pandas functions or python methods which can help me resolve the issue.

Thank you

i tried df.apply to flatten the list of json request.
tried df.explode method to break the pandas dictionary

tried df.to_string .. it works but, bigquery does not accept listed function as an input in table.

Comment: please edit your question to provide a reproducible input (`df1[['tags']].to_dict('list')`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use serial slicing with the [`str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) accessor:

```
df1['tags'].str[0].str['group']
```

The first slicing (`df1['tags'].str[0]`) gives you the dictionary, the second one (`.str['group']`) accesses the key.

Example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'tags': [[],
                             [{'group': 'generic', 'value': 'xxx'}],
                             [{'nogroup': 'xxx'}]]
                   })
df1['group'] = df1['tags'].str[0].str['group']
```

Output:

```
                                     tags    group
0                                      []      NaN
1  [{'group': 'generic', 'value': 'xxx'}]  generic
2                    [{'nogroup': 'xxx'}]     None
```

You could do the same with a list comprehension but you would have to handle the missing values manually:

```
df1['group'] = [l[0].get('group', None)
                if len(l)>0 and isinstance(l[0], dict)
                else pd.NA
                for l in df1['tags']]
```